# Смешались кнопки в телеграм-боте

Tags: python, sql, telegram-bot, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Написал код телеграм-бота, начал проверять и тестировать. Возникает проблема: когда я **отправляю фото или видео**, он мне выдает текст (всё правильно, как задумано), но когда я **нажимаю на кнопки** (Удалить фото\видео, удалить сообщение), то **выполняется почему-то кнопка "Пользователи"**, хотя должны быть (Удалить фото\видео, удалить сообщение).

**Почему выполняются другие кнопки?**
**Что написано не правильно?**
**Как исправить?**

````
import telebot
import time
from telebot import types
import webbrowser
import sqlite3

token_bot = ''
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token_bot)

name = None


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'<b>Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}</b>  \n\n', parse_mode='html')

    conn = sqlite3.connect('All_base.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id int auto_increment primary key, name varchar(30), pass varchar(30))')
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'  Поиск пользователя в системе...\n'
                                      f'Введите <b>ИМЯ</b>: ...', parse_mode='html')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_name)


def user_name(message):
    global name
    name = message.text.strip()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'  Сверяем данные пользователя...\n'
                                      f'Введите <b>ПАРОЛЬ</b>: ...', parse_mode='html')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_pass)


def user_pass(message):
    password = message.text.strip()
    conn = sqlite3.connect('All_base.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, pass) VALUES('%s', '%s')" % (name, password))
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn_all_users = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Список пользователей', callback_data='users')
    markup.add(btn_all_users)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Данные проверены  ✅. Вы зарегистрированы!', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback(call):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('All_base.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
    users = cur.fetchall()  # возвращает все найденные записи

    info = ''
    for el in users:
        info += f' Имя: {el[1]}\n'\
                f' Пароль: {el[2]}\n\n'  # ищем по элементам, не по индексу

    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f'```<b>Пользователи</b>```\n\n' 
                                           f'<code>{info}</code>', parse_mode='html')


    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo', 'picture', 'image'])
def get_photo(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn_delete_photo = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Удалить фото', callback_data='delete_file')
    btn_edit_photo = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Удалить сообщение', callback_data='delete')
    markup.add(btn_delete_photo, btn_edit_photo)
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Я не работаю с фотографиями, они для меня "пустой звук".', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['video'])
def get_video(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn_delete_video = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Удалить видео', callback_data='delete_file')
    btn_edit_video = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Удалить сообщение', callback_data='delete')
    markup.add(btn_delete_video, btn_edit_video)
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Я не работаю с видео, они для меня "пустой звук".', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def delete_message(callback_delete):
    if callback.data == 'delete_file':  # функция, которая удаляет предыдущее сообщение
        bot.delete_message(callback_delete.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id - 1)
    elif callback.data == 'delete':  # функция, которая удаляет сообщение
        bot.delete_message(callback_delete.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id)


bot.infinity_polling()
````